# What is the proper syntax for using state within a function

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get a modal to appear based on it's state. I used to have this code in a class and it worked but when I use a function I get the error "can't find variable state". What is the proper syntax to use state in this case, and why is it different in a function vs a class. Thank you for any help.

```
export default function MacrosList(){

    state = {
        isModalVisible: false
    };

    toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
    };

    return(
    <BottomModal
       visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
       onTouchOutside={() => {
       this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
    }}>

    <ModalContent>
       <Button> Add </Button>
       <Button> Subtract </Button>
    </ModalContent>
    </BottomModal>
    </View>
    )

}
```

Comment: if you want to access state inside a functional component you need to use react-hook.

Comment: Oh I see how this fits together now, Hooks are for use of state within functions rather than just classes. Thank you for the clarification I was curious as to if we can use regular state syntax within functions but I guess not.